# When I use the count function for a primary key, it only returns with 1 row, what is the problem here?

Tags: mysql

I tried to use an inner join statement for `b.bookingID` and `ba.bookingID` but it did not work and said alias 'b' didn't exist.

```
select c.customerid, customerfname,customerlname, count(b.bookingid) as 
'No. of Bookings', flightdate, arrivaltime, departtime, 
b.price, status, taxespaid, ba.bagpayment, p.PaymentAmount, 
pt.paymentcode
from booking b, flight f, baggage ba, payment p, paymenttype pt, customer 
c
where b.bookingID=ba.bookingid
and pt.paymentcode=p.paymentcode
and f.flightnum=b.flightnum
and c.customerid=b.customerID
;
```

The expected results would show all information associated with each specific booking. So instead of returning 1 row where it shows `count(b.bookingID)` as 3,000, it would show the 76 bookings in the database, and the count of each booking.

Comment: Without a group by an aggregate function will return 1 value over the entire resultset. AND you should revert to using explicit joins (ie inner or left) rather than comma seperated

Answer (score 0):

If you want know the numer of all the distinct  bookingid  then you need  count(distinct bookingid)

```
select c.customerid, customerfname,customerlname
    , count(distinct  b.bookingid) as 
'No. of Bookings', flightdate, arrivaltime
, departtime, 
b.price, status, taxespaid, ba.bagpayment
, p.PaymentAmount, 
pt.paymentcode
from booking b, flight f, baggage ba, payment p, paymenttype pt, customer c
where b.bookingID=ba.bookingid
and pt.paymentcode=p.paymentcode
and f.flightnum=b.flightnum
and c.customerid=b.customerID
;
```

count() return the numer of not null rows  based on your condition

so `count(*)` return all the rows not null,

`count(bookingid)` return all the not null rows with column bookingid not null

and last  `count(distinct bookingid)` retrun the numer of the distinct value for bookingid   in your case do the fact the bookingid    is unique the number of the booking

*anyway the use of aggregagtion function without a proper group for columns not involved in aggreagtion function work (by defauly) only for mysql version < 5.7  for mysql version starting from mysql 5.7  this behaviour is nota allowed  and you should add  the column not in aggreagtion function if group by*